# Discrepancies in Histogram after Stack Reslicing

Tags: image, histogram, analysis, imagej, fiji

I have a stack of 150 slice in the plane XY of a composite material. I resliced the stack so that I get the YZ projection and then, I performed the same processes, in parallell with a macro, over the stack in the XY and YZ just to double check the results.

I applied to them a filter (3D-Mean: Radius 3) and then transformed them to 8-bit scale. I was expecting to get the same histogram for both stacks since their original histogram was the same and they contain the exact same information, BUT, a change in the histogram happened after the Filtering. See table below:

[image]

What could be the discrepancy between the histograms in the XY-stack and the re-sliced YZ-stack after filtering? Why the 3D-Mean Filter gives me a different result depending on wether it is applied to a XY stack or a YZ stack?

This thing is kind of driving me crazy!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted and answered here:
https://forum.image.sc/t/discrepancies-in-histogram-after-reslice/28603

Edit:
Summary of the cause of the problem:
By default, ImageJ uses brightness contrast settings to scale intensities when quantizing.

Summary of the solution:
Ensure brightness/contrast settings are identical before converting to 8bit.

Comment: Hi there! Answers only providing a link are discouraged, because the answer will be worthless if the link breaks. Could you give the solution here as an answer? (Without plagiarizing)